# is (let { items } = user) strictly the same as saying (user.items)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested, array.prototype.map

Am trying to arrive at the answer below in a different way.

**Using `let {items} = user` to destructure instead of `user.items`.**

But using `let {items} = user` doesn't return the original array changed *(adding "!" to the items)*.

```js
const array = [
    {
        username: "john",
        team: "red",
        score: 5,
        items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
    },
    {
        username: "becky",
        team: "blue",
        score: 10,
        items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
    },
    {
        username: "susy",
        team: "red",
        score: 55,
        items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
    },
    {
        username: "tyson",
        team: "green",
        score: 1,
        items: ["book", "pen"]
    },

];
```

**Approach 1:**
It doesn't change items within `array` and returns the entire array without changes in the end.

```js
// BONUS: 
// create a new list with all user information, 
// but add "!" to the end of each items they own.

const newList = array.map(user => {
  let { items } = user;
  items = items.map(item => {
    return item + "!"
  });
  return user;
});
```

**Approach 2:**
However, this way seems to work.

```
const answer = array.map(user => {
  user.items = user.items.map(item => {
    return item + "!"
  });
  return user;
});
```

Here's my observation:

- `user.items` is grabs items within the `array` and subsequently return array with changes, but
- `let { items } = user` does not allow for the changes to be implemented to the returned array.

I'd want to know why the above happens.

Comment: reassigning `user.items` is not the same as reassigning `items` ... you'd need to add `user.items = items` to the first code

Comment: Destructuring is just a shorthand for assigning variables from properties, it doesn't make the variable a reference to the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not seeing the change because you are reassigning a local variable instead of the `user.items` property. Take a look at the slightly modified code and hopefully it will be apparent why it's not working.

```
const newList = array.map(user => {
    // Instead of using destructuring assignment
    // let's manually do the same thing.
    //let { items } = user;
    let items = user.items;
    // Now items will be replaced by the result from map()
    items = items.map(item =>{
        return item + "!"
    });
    // user is returned without ever modifying user.items
    return user;
});
```